# Referencing js files from an html file in Quickbase

Tags: javascript, html, flot, quickbase

I am trying to build a flot chart using data from Quickbase. In order to accomplish this I have to be able to reference the flot.js files. In my html page I have scripts that call the js files located in Quickbase where the src is equal to the url link to the read-only version of the js file. However, the html page does not seem to be referencing the js pages. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a script similar to this, but replace the part before .quickbase, the db, and the pagename value.

```
<script src="https://haversineconsulting.quickbase.com/db/bipznmwx8?a=dbpage&pagename=myscript.js"></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="bipznmwx8?a=dbpage&pagename=myscript.js"></script>
```

See https://quickbase-community.intuit.com/questions/811560-javascript-libraries